# If I denied the permission of the running app, the app data will disappear

Tags: android

If I denied the permission of the running app, the app data will disappear.

The way to change the permission was done in settings.

Step.

1. run my app.
2. switch my app to the background.
3. run settings app.
4. change the permissions of my app.
5. switch my app to the foreground.
6. My app variable data disappears.

```
UserManager.getInstance().getUserMe()
```

This is static data.
The data disappears and sendbird connection will be disconnected.

Why is this happening?

Comment: please show the code

Comment: I don't know how to show you the code.. What's being checked is that the app's process ID changes and the adb connection is disconnected.

Comment: Oh, right! The way to change the permission was done in settings.

Comment: Your process is indeed killed when you deny a permission, but that doesn't mean your app data is destroyed - how are you saving your state? Please include the code that has your 'app variable data'.

Comment: It is normal behaviour that the app restarts when you revoke permissions.

Comment: Um... now I'm understand. Can I ask you one more time? Why is there activity stack left when the app is restarted?